# pnpm in monorepo - how to run a command only in a specific package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, monorepo, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

Let's say I want to install a package in a specific package in my monorepo, how do I do this from root?

in npm, you can do this with something like this:

```
npm install react --workspace=a
```

I searched the docs and I can't find a way to do this in pnpm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is called "filtering" in pnpm docs ([see it here](https://pnpm.io/filtering)).

In this case, you would run:

```
pnpm --filter=a add react
```

or

```
pnpm -F=a add react
```

Comment: --filter works, thanks! -F doesn't for some reason though.

Comment: It's worth noting that the filter will looking for the "name" in the package's "package.json" file, not the name of the package directory.